Pass props to parent route element
I have a <Background /> element upstream of the child pages.

const myRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <ParentLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/red-page',
        element: <RedPage />,
      },
      {
        path: '/green-page',
        element: <GreenPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);


// ParentLayout.tsx
export const ParentLayout = ({ bgColor }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Background color={bgColor} />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

Each child pages should be able to set the background color. What is the best way to achieve that?
(Please keep in mind that it is a toy example, the goal is not really to set the background color, which could be obviously done with a quick DOM/css hack)
Ideal solution
Any child could somehow declare that they need a bgColor="red". React would then proceed to render ParentLayout and the child page.
Issue: Children are rendered after ParentLayout, so it is probably not possible.
Working solution: Using loaders
This works ok, but it has two cons:

We are hacking the loader's primary raison d'être (async data loading).
The declaration of background color is taken out of the child component (violates a bit the SoC principle)


const myRouter = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <ParentLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/red-page',
        element: <RedPage />,
        loader: () => ({ bgColor: 'red' }),
      },
      {
        path: '/green-page',
        element: <GreenPage />,
        loader: () => ({ bgColor: 'green' }),
      },
    ],
  },
]);


// ParentLayout.tsx
export const ParentLayout = () => {
  const { bgColor } = useLoadedData()
  return (
    <>
      <Background color={bgColor} />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

Working solution: Use useEffect / useLayoutEffect

// ParentLayout.tsx
export const ParentLayout = () => {
  const {bgColor} = useSomeStorageOrAContext();
  return (
    <>
      <Background color={bgColor} />
      <Outlet />
    </>
  );
};

// RedPage.tsx
export const RedPage = () => {
  const {setBgColor} = useSomeStorageOrAContext();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setBgColor('red')
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>My Red Page</div>
  );
};

This approach has the benefit of keeping the route declaration pure, and leaving to the children the choice to modify the background themselves.
Cons:

The ParentLayout will be rendered twice. This can possibly be alleviated by using useLayoutEffect to prevent the first unnecessary painting. But it still seems unnecessarily heavy.
Such imperative approach is meh. I would love a declarative approach.

Is there a cannonical approach for that?
